# How To Change Color Of <td> element depending on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to change the color of a  element in the table depending on if the value is positive or negative, currently this is what I have but it is not working properly and is n^2 which I find sort of inefficient:

```
export const ActiveStockList = () => {
  const store = useStockListStore();

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ColorTest");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
      if (x[i].charAt(j) != "-") {
        x[i].style.Color = "green";
      } else {
        x[i].style.Color = "red";
      }
    }
  }

  return useObserver(() =>
    store.stocks.map((stock) => (
      <tr>
        <td className="justify-content-center">
          <a href={"/stocks/" + stock.symbol}>{stock.symbol}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{+stock.latestVolume}</td>
        <td className="ColorTest">
          {(+stock.changePercent * 100).toFixed(2)}%
        </td>
        <td className="ColorTest">$ {+stock.change}</td>
        <td>$ {+stock.latestPrice}</td>
        <td className="ColorTest">{(+stock.ytdChange * 100).toFixed(2)}%</td>
        <td>Buy</td>
        <td>10,023,000</td>
        <td>89.23</td>
        <td>140,000</td>
      </tr>
    ))
  );
};
```

what is the best way to change the three  elements to either green or red depending if their value is greater than 0 or less than 0? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion. Write it as an inline style. No need to modify the dom the way you are doing it with React. Use the actual number and a logic check:

```
style={stockNumber <= 0 ? {color: "red"} : {color: "green"}}
```

Or whatever logic. Turn it into a function that returns the style object if you don't want to repeat the logic over and over.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to set the colors by iterating over the matching elements.

You can just set the `style` attribute in-place.

For example, instead of

```
<td className="ColorTest">$ {+stock.change}</td>
```

you could have:

```
<td style={{ color: stock.change < 0 ? "red" : "green"}}>$ {+stock.change}</td>
```